# Understanding Spaces in Python

Tags: python

I am a beginner in Python. I know spaces play a significant role for compiling. So I have the following two classes in the same python script file:

```
class ClassA:
  def __init__(self):
     self.x = {}
  def _methodA1():
    # Something
  def _methodA2():
    # Something

class ClassB:
  def _methodB1():
    # Something
  def _methodB2():
    # Something

def MethodX():
  print "Hello World"
```

(1) Which class `MethodX` belongs to?

(2) Can we say `ClassB` is an inner class of `ClassA` ?

(3) If `MethodX` belongs to ClassA, does it mean `self.x` is accessible via `MethodX` ?

Comment: `MethodX` doesn't belong to a class since it is not indented under a class.

Comment: It seems that something may be wrong with your formatting? As formatting is what your question is about I recommend you change that to get a more accurate answer.

Comment: Smells like homework

Comment: No it is not homework. I am learning Python by my self.

Comment: It does not belong to either class. It is a standalone function. Having the name `Method` does not make it a method. Being indented in a class block is one way to have a function become a method of that class.

Comment: In Python, a line falls into the scope of the first less-indented line above it.

Comment: are you already a programmer?  if so, the general idea with Python is that most programmers generally already indent code for readability in most languages.  Python makes it formally significant.  a big rule to keep in mind is that your indentation has to be consistent in a block (class, method, if, for, etc...)  .  i.e. you can 2 spaces indent (4 is norm) on methodA and 4 on methodB.  but you cant mix and match multiple indents in the same block.

Answer (score 8):

1. `MethodX` belongs to no class, it's a global function, not a method of one of the classes
2. No, because `ClassA` and `ClassB` are at identical indentation; an inner class of `ClassA` would match the indentation of the method definitions in `ClassA`
3. Since it belongs to no class, `MethodX` has no direct access to attributes of any instance. Beyond that, `self` must be explicitly accepted as the first positional argument by methods; since `MethodX` doesn't accept `self`, it can't access it. All of your methods are broken because of this; unless decorated with `@staticmethod`, they need to accept at least one positional argument (which is called `self` by convention on regular methods, and `cls` by convention on `@classmethod`s).

Comment: Thank you for your explanation

Answer (score 2):

Yes, space is important to python, the level of indentation used for blocks and statements is how the scope of those statements is established.

MethodX isn't a method it's a top level function, not associated with an instance of an object or called via a Class.

ClassB isn't an inner class of ClassA. You *can* nest classes in python, because class introduces another level of block scope, which do nest, but it's quite unusual to do so, it doesn't confer many benefits, and it makes some scoping behaviours look more confusing (i.e. referencing class attributes in the enclosing class scope)

MethodX doesn't have access to ClassA.x via self because it's not in the scope of ClassA. Furthermore, you have to declare self as an explicit parameter in python - the reference to the object instance is passed automatically as the first parameter to methods, but there is no binding automatically created for it. In fact `self` is a convention, not a formal keyword. `_methodA1` and `_methodA2` do have method scope, because they're defined within the scope of ClassA, but they don't declare a self binding

Answer (score 1):

1. MethodX doesn't belong to either class A or B.
2. ClassB is not an "inner" class of ClassB.
3. Irrelevant because it's not the case.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation

Comment: Pleasure. It's short, but to the point. @ShadowRanger 's answer gives you a bit more of the why and what for, so I'd tick his (or hers) answer if you were to tick any.

Answer (score 0):

Stuff with the same indentation is generally on the same "level" (unindented = "file level").

Block which is indented "belongs" to first statement before it, which is indented less than it.

Example:

```
class A:         # "file level"
    def b(self): # "belongs to" class A
        if True: # "belongs to" b
            pass # "belongs to" the if

def x(): # "file level"
    pass # "belongs to" x
    pass # same as above
```